# Simple JS executes but doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple web page like so:

```js
/*global define*/
/*jslint vars: true, plusplus: true, devel: true, nomen: true, indent: 4,     maxerr: 50*/
/*global $ */
$(function alap() {

  "use strict";
  var TEST_BOXCOUNT = 5;

  function Tile(name, date, time, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
    this.description = description;
  }
  $('#boxCount').on('input', function(event) {
    var boxCount = Number(event.target.value);
    var boxContainer = $('#boxContainer');
    boxContainer.empty();
    console.log("so far so good");
    for (var i = 1; i <= boxCount; i++) {
      console.log("in loop");
      var box = $('<div>').addClass('box');
      boxContainer.append(box);
    }
  })



});
```

```css
#controls>label {
  display: block;
}

#boxes {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls">
  <label for="boxCount">Box count?</label>
  <input type="text" id="boxCount">
</div>
<div id="boxContainer"></div>
```

The intention is to drop down some boxes as tiles, the quantity is the input value. I have those logs input, and actually they **execute**, I see the appropriate count of `log` calls. The problem is that nothing appears.

It is strange that the exact same code worked when using in `JSFiddle`, but unsure why no boxes show up here. I request assistance to sort this out.

**EDIT:**

As you see, I have a `TEST_BOXCOUNT` and a `Prototype` definition in place. I'm not using them right now, but later on I'll make these boxes clickable with some info on them. They aren't supposed to do anything in this case though.

**What it logs:**

> alap.js:20 so far so good
>
> alap.js:22 in loop
>
> alap.js:20 so far so good
>
> 12 alap.js:22 in loop

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, when i run it and write 12 in the input, i get 12 boxes

Comment: lol :D I'm using Brackets and chrome. What did you use?

Comment: Same, i just added a bit css so i can see the boxed if added

    .box{
      height: 20px;
      margin: 5px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: blue;
    }

Comment: Maybe box class is invisible? Can you add the css for box?

Comment: [I did the same as @CarstenLøvboAndersen](https://jsfiddle.net/5a928mfq/). In your code there is no `box` class, so we just added one so they can be seen.

Comment: Use jQuery's shorthands that are available, don't just mix vanilla JS and jQuery -- it obstructs readability.

Comment: Added the line @CarstenLøvboAndersen suggested, but still no luck :/

Comment: Then you're doing something different obviously. Post your code and what the console logs or tells you is wrong. You can't just say "it's not working" and expect us to magically know what's wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Sure, posting those logs in a second

Comment: You might want to replace `window.onload` with `$(function () { ... });` (jQuery shorthand for `document.ready`) to ensure the DOM has loaded before you run your code.

Comment: Added what you said, and indeed it works here as well. 
Still no luck on Brackets and Chrome. Shall I try to run it on something else?

Comment: You need to try and find what is causing the issue.  This can give you some hints [mcve].  You've already tried this (the code in this question) and found that this is *not* what's causing your issue.  So you need to find what *is* causing the issue.

Comment: Coming from a background with statically typed languages, this web development looks a bit hard to debug :/ However, thanks for all of your advices. I'll go ahead and mess around with this a bit more.

Comment: Agreed, statically typed languages give you more predictability up front. But you can get used to it! Your browser's developer tools are very powerful like an IDE and you can set breakpoints in your code, even modify it during execution, watch and amend variable values etc, which should make debugging much more pleasant. IMHO Chrome has the best tools but YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing else to say. I just copy pasted all my stuff to a new folder and it works like a charm.

The only thing I can think of is, that my old project was in my `OneDrive` folder, and it may be protected (against viruses to execute), or because of my slow net connection it timed out. These are just hypotheses, I really have no clue why it works, but it works.

So again, move you project to anywhere that's not in a cloud saver folder, and it might solve the issue.